# Upload captured image from Phonegap app to WordPress REST API

Tags: wordpress, cordova, vue.js, phonegap

I'm developing an app with PhoneGap (Vue, Framework7) and a WordPress backend.

I'm trying to upload a captured image to the WordPress backend through the media REST API endpoint (using axios), but I get an error back.

The image is displayed correctly in the app (using DATA_URL - base64 encoding), but when I try to upload it to the endpoint it throws an error.

```
const apiHost = 'https://example.com/wp-json'
let image_form_data = new FormData

// self.images[0] is the first base64 encoded image stored in a Vuex store
// self.jwToken is the JavaScript Web Token string
image_form_data.append( 'file', self.images[0] )

const imagesOptions = {
  method: 'post',
  url: apiHost + '/wp/v2/media',
  headers: {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
    "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + self.jwToken,
    "Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename=\"uploaded_image.png\"",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
  },
  data: image_form_data
}

axios( imagesOptions )
.then( (imgResp) => {
  console.log('imgResp')
  console.log(imgResp)
} )
```

It throws an error:

```
URL: https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media
State: 500 Internal Server Error
Source: Network
```

The server is set to accept 16M file upload, so it shouldn't be a problem (but who knows?).

But I've already got error like "resource not allowed for security reasons" (bypassed with `define('ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS', true);` in wp-config.php).

I could solve it earlier with a custom API endpoint and using a filereader / blob, but it is important now for me to use the "official" endpoint.

Has somebody any idea how to solve this? (I've already read a lot of posts on SO (and elsewhere), but nothing worked.)

Comment: It seems problem is at wordpress configuration, for security reasons, you should try to make simple php file and upload photo to some folder, without any wordpress configuration. It's easy. - Check [this](https://makitweb.com/capture-and-upload-photo-to-server-with-phonegap/) out

Comment: Also, you are in wrong way. You must call some php file for uploading, and not sending photo to wordpress json api.. ?

Comment: Dear @Pablo: 1. **it is important now for me to use the "official" endpoint**, so a simple PHP won't really do it (it has to get in my WP) - and I wouldn't want to extend the API for this task with new functions. 2. No, this is not the "wrong" way, as `POST`ing to the media endpoint of the WP REST API is exactly for this - uploading content (like image files) to the WP installation. 3. In the case of WP, a REST API endpoint is actually a PHP file prepared for handling REST requests.